# function containing messagebox.show fails to popup if caller running as windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, windows-services, messagebox

Application A is running as a windows service.
Application A runs a `checkingforerrors()` inside an if.

Application B is an exe which is also a system tray icon.
Application B has a function for performing `MessageBox.Show("message");`

Also created a blank Windows Form in lieu of the `MessageBox.Show("message");`

Application B

```cs
public static void checkingforerrors()
{
    MessageBox.Show("ALERT");
}
```

Application A

```cs
checkforerrorsfrommonitor.checkingforerrors();
```

Expected that because my Monitor.exe application has the `MessageBox`, that there would not be the issue of services interacting with desktop.

Here's the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

Comment: Note that if I run my Windows service application as a console application, I will see the popups from the messagebox and the blank win form.

Comment: Application A needs to send a message to any running instance of Application B and have Application B present the dialog. That's how it's widely done, ever since Vista put up that barrier.

Comment: What is the question, exactly? The error provides an explanation and a remediation. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: More and more I am thinking this is by design and is a security-related type issue. 
I have a case where if a condition is met it should be considered an immediate action item.

Comment: @JohnWu the question is why cant the service run a function of another application to perform a messagebox.show. I think the answer is that 'interact with the desktop' is restricted whether directly or indirectly attempted.

Comment: It's not running a function in another application, it's running another application's function in its own process space. There's no "indirect" method involved here. Application A is using Application B as a class library.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work. A Windows Service will also run if no User is logged on. So if nobody is there to read it. And it will stop, as long as nobody presses "OK" (in case it would work".
This is was ment by "UserInteractiveMode".

Usually a Windows Service writes messages in a Log_File, or in a Database, where it can be picked up by people that are interested.